# Tensorflow Object Detection API - Detecting the humans not wearing Helmet

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

*** Please note, my previous problem of detecting withouthelmet as NA is resolved.

Now I have a new issue, I used 1000 images for detecting humans not wearing helmets and also 1000 images for humans wearing helmet and 1000 images for only humans. I used SSD_mobilenet_v1_pets.config file for training.

Here is my pbtxt file

```
item {
    id: 1
    name: 'withouthelmet'
}
item {
    id: 2
    name: 'withhelmet'
}
item {
    id: 3
    name: 'person'
}
```

sample training Image
[image]

After the training my model detect every car as person..

[image]

**Is that because of using ssd_mobilenet model(id: 1 for person but I used id: 1 as withouthelmet and id:3 for car but I used id:3 for person)**

Pls help me to solve this problem

Comment: You can't simply add a class like that, you either have to work with a model which predicts the person with helmet, or have to work with whole 91 categories. There is no option to add 1 extra in the already trained model that is as much as I know till now.

Comment: Did you train model yourself or used a pre-trained model?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Pls let me know any of the model for detect humans not wearing helmet.

Comment: Yeah.. I train the model. @  Le Duong Tuan Anh

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you set num_classes to 1 in your config?
2. Please note that min_negatives_per_image means min # of negative anchors (instead of images) so you data mix has nothing to do with this parameter.

I had to modify earlier answer - if you add a background image(image with no gt boxes) to the dataset, it should help reduce false positives. Sorry I got confused with some other stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Zhichao Lu, yes.. I have set num_classes to 1.  For negative images I have give zero groundtruth boxes. As you said now I removed all the negative images and added two more classes. Then I have a new problem.. pls check the question.

Comment: @Zhichao Lu Adding background images with no gt boxes means we need to add some images in training set which are not part of the object and continue the process of creating csv files, tfrecord and training?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the pre-trained SSD-MobileNetV1 model trained on the pets dataset?
I think you better use a model trained on COCO dataset since it has persons, in contrast to pets.
Of course that if you train your model it will learn to detect the person as well, but since you don't have a lot of examples of persons without a helmet, it would probably be better to start with a model which knows what a person is.

Regarding your questions, if you only want to detect people without helmet, you can simply drop everything else in the pbtxt file, only put

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'withouthelmet'
  display_name: 'withouthelmet'
}
```

change the number of categories in the config file to 1, and fine-tune the model.

Comment: Thank for your reply.. I will increase the data set to 1000 and I will make the changes and let you know the result..

Comment: I did all the changes.. Now I had another problem. It detects every person as without helmet

Comment: The examples you gave it so far are of people. How can it distinguish between person with helmet or without? Only if you also give it negative examples, i.e. of people with helmets.
EDIT: Do you mean that you only want to detect person as without helmet if he's on a motorcycle? Than once again you need to give it negative examples so the model will learn to distinguish - of people not on motorcycle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Yes I only want to detect person without helmet on a motorcycle. so to distinguish person without helmet, I will add two more classes  - Class 1 -- withouthelmet, Class 2 -- person, Class 3 - withhelmet, Can you please let me know, If this process is correct.

Comment: You can, but you don't have to add these as classes, but rather as example. Add examples of (1) people, (2) people on motorcycles with helmets, both without the label of 'withouthelmet'. This way the model will learn that it's not enough that a person is present, and that you're not interested in a person on a motorcycle with a helmet, but only in the case that a person is both on a motorcycle and without a helmet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I make the changes and let you know the result.

Comment: I made the changes you said but still it detects every person as without helmet. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: How much negative examples have you provided? I think that for every positive example (person on motor without helmet) you should provide at least 2 negative example (person not on motor) in the same batch.
An alternative option is to decouple the problem. Train on whether a person is with or without a helmet, and train on detecting motorcycles, and then filter the detections by your need with a postprocessing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I provided 2000 negative images.. 1000 for person with helmet on motorcycle and 1000 for person.

Comment: I made some changes in the question... Pls clarify my doubts.